# External devices acting up after messing with graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth, webcam

I had an issue with my Nvidia GPU drivers and ended up needing to fight my system to get the proprietary ones back up and running. I fixed that issue, but now am faced with another issue: lots of my system's USB/external devices (webcam, Bluetooth dongle, Xbox controller, all audio outputs and speakers etc...) that worked only 30 minutes prior are not functioning at all now.

For example, USB devices are listed by my system (i.e. I can run `lsusb` and the webcam, controller and Bluetooth dongle appear), but the Cheese webcam program says 'no device found', and the Gnome settings Bluetooth section just tells me to plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth even though my dongle is plugged in to the same spot it was before.

Even stranger still, my mouse and keyboard (both USB) seem to be fine and still work.

Kind of lost as everything was working before I removed and reinstalled the Nvidia drivers but now it seems to have had the unintended consequence of stopping lots of my other devices functioning and I have no idea why.

The main command I ran to get my GPU back running was `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` - maybe this has something to do with it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by booting into recovery mode via grub, and then selecting the  "dpkg | repair broken packages" option. There were a few kernel header related packages that it seemed to think needed removing and fixing, after a reboot everything is back to normal.

[image]